# how to scanf complete line containing spaces in c

Tags: c, scanf

Is there a way to scan a complete line containing spaces and store it inside one variable?

I tried a lot of things on the web like:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
scanf("%20[0-9a-zA-Z ]", str);
scanf("%20[^\n]", str);
```

nothing works.

I have something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(){

    while (1) {
        int command = 0;
        printf("Enter a command(0-10):");
        scanf("%d", &command);
        switch (command) {
            case 4:
            {
                char message[20];
                printf("Please enter the message:");
                scanf("%s", message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I enter value 4 for "command" variable and then some input that contains spaces for "message" array like : "hello all"
then I enter in infinite loop and I don't know why?

I thought of something like scanf("%s[\n]", message); as I want to read till I reach a new line but that gives worse results (Please till me the meaning of %s[\n] in this scenario, is it same meaning of what I thought of).

So how can I scan complete line containing spaces and what is the meaning of scanf("%s[\n]",message) in general?

**Update:**

Actually, I tried using fgets before but it gave worse result for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){

    while (1) {
        int command = 0;
        printf("Enter a command(0-10):");
        scanf("%d", &command);
        switch (command) {
            case 4:
            {
                char message[20];
                printf("Please enter the message:");
            fgets (message, 20, stdin);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

here the program is skipping reading "message", could you try it guys. Is there something I am missing.

Comment: Make it easy on yourself: just use `fgets`.  Almost anything you try to do with `scanf` is harder than it ought to be, and can be dome more cleanly and more reliably with functions other than `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf("%s", message);` --> `scanf(" %19[^\n]", message);`

Comment: The problem with your program is probably that after you read the command number with `scanf %d`, the newline is still sitting in the input buffer, so then when you try to read the message line, you read just that newline (which therefore looks like a blank line) instead.  This is a very, very, very common problem, and a very frustrating one.  There are ways around it, but they're all harder than just not using `scanf` in the first place.  (But this does mean you can't use `scanf` to read the command number, either.)

Comment: The `%s` format stops at the first whitespace. So if you entered two words, the next `%d` format will stall at the second text word. It does not got away, you have to read the input somehow.

Comment: @SteveSummit leading whitespace is filtered out by `%d` and by `%s` format specifiers.

Comment: The sad truth about `scanf` is that no one uses it to read input in real programs -- its sole use is to (try to) read input in "teaching" programs written by beginning programmers who haven't learned how to use `fgets` yet.  So `scanf` is basically like a pair of training wheels on a bicycle -- except that `scanf` works so poorly and is so hard to use, it's much more like trying to learn to ride a bicycle with *square* training wheels attached.

Comment: @WeatherVane True, but *not* by `%[]`, which is one of the things he was trying.

Comment: Guys, please check the update

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read a *line* then simple and robust solution is to use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html). Just don't use `scanf()` at all (relevant: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)).

`fgets()` has one caveat - it'll read in the newline as well if the buffer has enough space which you need to take care.

Comment: @MosabShaheen, no the `fgets` will catch the newline left in the input buffer after `scanf("%d", &command);`. Don't mix your methods. Use `fgets` for both, you can then apply `sscanf` in the first case.

Comment: Change `scanf("%d", &command);` to `fgets (message, 20, stdin); sscanf(message, "%d", &command);` but you need to do error checking of *all* input statements.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks that partially solved the issue, but now I am facing another one which is: fgets when used to input a string it takes the new line as part of the string so how to exclude that new line.

Comment: @MosabShaheen Try a Google search on "fgets remove newline".

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks, you know there is one thing makes you wonder: when c developers build the c language did they test it before releasing it to the market :)

Comment: @MosabShaheen To remove newline: `char buf[256]; if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { char *p = strchr(buf, '\n'); if (p) *p = 0; }`

Comment: @usr thanks, I used message[strlen(message)-1]='\0' instead

Comment: @MosabShaheen That's problematic if string is empty i.e. when `strlen(message)` is 0.

Comment: @usr but it will never be empty as there is new line at least.

Comment: @MosabShaheen I know what you mean, but it's a risky argument.  In general, if you want to remove the last newline character, it's much safer to check that it's a newline character, rather than blindly removing the last character.  You may think you've convinced yourself that the last character has to be the newline, but what if you're wrong?  And in fact there are two ways for the last character not to be a newline: (1) the input line was longer than your input buffer, (2) EOF occurred without a newline character.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for the notice. It can be better to check the last character.